# mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize not work

Tags: mapreduce, mapper

I have a mapreduce job.

my `dfs.blockSize` is `134217728 (128M)`. I have a very huge hive table which has `189` blocks, I don't want to create `189` mappers (consume too much memory).

I set `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=268435456 (256M)`, but the job still create `189` to run. Suppose this setting will reduce mapper number, but it didn't work.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your job? Are you running a spark job or normal MR job?

Comment: normal MR job, edited in question

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, you can try the others configuration, such as `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.node` and `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.rack`, I works for me when I set these two configuration.